# Pig latin in Bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, conditional-statements

This pig latin translator works for all words that start with a vowel; however, this script does not print anything when an argument starts with a consonant

```
PIGIFY=$1
vowels=(a e i o u A E I O U)
CHECK=0
for element in $vowels; do
    if [[ $element == ${PIGIFY:0:1} ]]
    then
        echo ${PIGIFY}ay
        break
    fi
    if [ $CHECK -eq 9 ]
    then
       echo ${PIGIFY:1}${PIGIFY:0:1}way
    fi   
    CHECK=$(( CHECK+1 ))
done
```

My script will try to compare the first letter of the argument to all possible vowels, including capital letters. Once we have reacher U and we find that the word does not start with U, the counter should be equal to 9, and then I want the second part to be echoed. I'm wondering if my second conditional is in right form or if I messed up my increment for my counter.

Comment: `$vowels` expands to just `a`, as it is equivalent to `${vowels[0]}`. You probably meant `"${vowels[@]}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to do all of this logic inside your for loop, just set a variable if a vowel is found, break the loop, and then do your echo afterwards based on the new variable:

```
PIGIFY=$1
vowels=(a e i o u A E I O U)
for element in $vowels; do
    if [[ $element == ${PIGIFY:0:1} ]]
    then
        startswithvowel=true
        break
    fi
done

if [ $startswithvowel ]; then
        echo ${PIGIFY}ay
else
        echo ${PIGIFY:1}${PIGIFY:0:1}way
fi
```